# Loading a BMP image into an object in vbscript

Tags: .net, vbscript, activex

Visual basic & .NET aren't my strong points, so forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question.

I'm using an activex component that captures signatures from a hardware device. I'm trying to load BMP images on the device's display.

The activex comes with good docs, and that's the function that responsible for drawing BMP on the display:

http://www.topazsystems.com/software/sigplushelp/Methods_and_Properties_for_use_with_LCD_Tablets/Graphics_Methods/LCDWriteBitmap.htm

That function accept some kind of HBITMAP / BitmapHandle object. Can someone give me an example on how to load a BMP object from a URL (not from a local file)?

I got another example written in .NET that does that, but I'm using vbscript with that activex. Here's that .NET example I found:

```
Dim WebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim sign As Bitmap
Dim strSign As String
strSign = "http://www.topazsystems.com/images/Sign.bmp"
sign = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(WebClient.OpenRead(strSign))

Dim HIcon As IntPtr = sign.GetHbitmap

AxSigPlus1.TabletState = 1
AxSigPlus1.DisplayWindowRes = True
AxSigPlus1.SetBackgroundHandle(HIcon.ToInt32, 0
```

**Edit (5/9/12):**

On second look, the activex is an OCX activex component and not a DLL.

Here's a demo vbscript script that comes with the SDK:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript"><!--

Sub LoadSig 
   If document.formname.txtValue2.value="" Then
      SigPlus1.ClearTablet()
      MsgBox "Please re-enter your first name to display signature"
   Else
      SigPlus1.JustifyX=10
      SigPlus1.JustifyY=10
      SigPlus1.AutoKeyStart
      SigPlus1.AutoKeyData=document.formname.txtValue2.value
      SigPlus1.AutoKeyData=document.formname.Disclaimer.value
      strDisclaimer2=document.formname.Disclaimer.value
      SigPlus1.AutoKeyFinish
      SigPlus1.EncryptionMode=1
      SigPlus1.SigCompressionMode=2
      SigPlus1.DisplayPenWidth=10
      SigPlus1.JustifyMode=5
      SigPlus1.SigString=document.formname.SigData.value

      If strDisclaimer=strDisclaimer2 Then
         If SigPlus1.NumberOfTabletPoints=0 Then
            MsgBox "Name does not match. Signature cannot be displayed"
         End If
      Else
         MsgBox "Disclaimer has been changed. Signature cannot be displayed"
      End If
   End If
end Sub

//--></SCRIPT>

<FORM NAME="formname">

<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="SigData">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="txtValue">
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:204px; left:10px;">
<b>Disclaimer information from the previous page:</b><br><br>
<INPUT TYPE="text" size=117 name="Disclaimer">
</DIV>

<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:252px; left:10px;">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<b>Please re-enter your first name to display signature:</b><br><br>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtValue2">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input id="DoneBtn" name="DoneBtn" type="button" value="Display" onclick="LoadSig" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #666699; COLOR: white; FONT: bold 8pt verdana" onmouseout="window.event.srcElement.style.background = '#666699'" onmouseover="window.event.srcElement.style.background = '#AFAFAF'">
</DIV>

</FORM>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--

//These Javascript functions grab the data passed via the GET method, and redistribute
//the data for use on this page

function replace(string,text,by) {
    // Replaces text with by in string
    var i = string.indexOf(text), newstr = '';
    if ((!i) || (i == -1))
        return string;
    newstr += string.substring(0,i) + by;
    if (i+text.length < string.length)
        newstr += replace(string.substring(i+text.length,string.length),text,by);
    return newstr;
}


function getParm(string,parm) {
    // returns value of parm from string
    var startPos = string.indexOf(parm + "=");
    if (startPos > -1) {
        startPos = startPos + parm.length + 1;
        var endPos = string.indexOf("&",startPos);
        if (endPos == -1)
            endPos = string.length;
        return unescape(string.substring(startPos,endPos));
    }
    return '';
}

var passed = replace(location.search.substring(1),"+"," ");

document.formname.SigData.value = getParm(passed,'SigData');
document.formname.txtValue.value = getParm(passed,'txtValue');
document.formname.Disclaimer.value = getParm(passed, 'Disclaimer');
strDisclaimer = document.formname.Disclaimer.value;

//--></SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Is your ActiveX component an ActiveX control (.ocx file) or is it an ActiveX dll?

Comment: I believe it's a activex dll written in visual basic.

Comment: Are you using VB.NET or VBScript?  They are two very different things.

Comment: it's a VBScript running on the client side. we can't customize the OCX activex component

Answer (score 4):

You should download the file and save temporarily. After doing this, you can get handle using [LoadPicture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66bd1sx9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. LoadPicture returns a `Picture` object with **Handle** property. I think this is what you need.

```
Dim Fso, Stm, WebCli, sign, HIcon, strTempPath
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strTempPath = Fso.BuildPath(Fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName), Fso.GetTempName)

Set Stm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    Stm.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    Stm.Open

Set WebCli = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    WebCli.open "GET", "http://www.topazsystems.com/images/Sign.bmp"
    WebCli.send
    Stm.Write WebCli.responseBody
    Stm.SaveToFile strTempPath
    Stm.Close

Set sign = LoadPicture(strTempPath)
HIcon = sign.Handle

AxSigPlus1.TabletState = 1
AxSigPlus1.DisplayWindowRes = True
AxSigPlus1.SetBackgroundHandle HIcon, 0

Set sign = Nothing
Fso.DeleteFile strTempPath 'remove temp file
```

Comment: thanks! is this a vbscript script i can use in webpages or do I need to recompile the activex with this modification?

Comment: my activex code is encapsulated in a <script></script> in my html page. this code doesn't run on the client side. any other ideas?

Comment: You could use it in a Webpage but it will only run in IE - only browser to support ActiveX controls. Or you could put it in a file ending with a VBS extension and shell it from .Net with Process.Start("C:\a.vbs"). It would be easier IMHO to do this with the WebClient class in the .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you could figure out how to convert between a byte array to a picture object you'd be golden: you could just have the server app load the picture from disk, convert it to a serious of codegenerated VBA assignments like 'ar(m)=v...' and then unconvert in VBA. I found all kinds of samples in VB6 but all were riddled with win32 API calls.

Good luck getting the client side to work with that though. Where I work we're converting a thick client app's that uses a signature pad to work on the web; this is what I intend to do:

Wrap it with your own OCX. Have it set itself Safe for Scripting, etc. and it can do what it wants, including writing files.

You're going to have to send your users the Topaz pads. they're going to have to install software. Just piggyback yours on the install. If they're buying the pads on their own, just have them download your installer.

And if you want to get really rich, you can get your wrapper signed and whatever so it will autodownload and set itself safe. Just be sure to make it very thin if you do that, there's overhead for upgrading.